# CakePHP v3.2.2 can i set up with php version 5.3

Tags: php, version, cakephp-3.2

I write project with cakephp 3.2 and I don't notice about PHP version while developing on localhost. When I upload hosting and I got blank page.

When i googling it. It cause of php version not compitable and cakephp 3 minimum require is php version 5.5.9.

is there a way to do cakephp 3 and php version 5.3 integrated?

Answer (score 0):

No. cakephp 3 is built with php 7 in mind hence why 5.5.9 is the minimum requirement. PHP 5.3 is almost 7 years old now so I'm not sure why you would still be developing applications for it? why can you not just upgrade php?

PHP has come along way since 5.3 so it only makes sense that new/updated frameworks evolve to support new versions of the language in favour of back dating to older versions

Comment: I was use latest version on localhost. I forgot about hosting server php version. when i upload on server. i found this error.

Comment: Sorry, I don't have any good news for you. Is upgrading out of the question?